# Bad sensor values with D1 Mini v.3 and soil moisture sensor

Tags: sensor, esp8266, humidity

I created a simple project using a D1 Mini v.3 connected with a Black 1.2 version soil moisture sensor.

Sensor is connected with 5V and the A0 pin on D1.

When I run this simple example:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  int rawValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(rawValue);
  
  delay(500);
}
```

I get 950 in the water and 1024 in the air.

This is a problem because the small range lead to a very unstable measuring.

Is this the normal behavior or I miss something?

**Update**

I tryied also in real and very wet moist soil:

[image]

But values never drops under 952 with 3 different sensors:

```
1024
1024
1024
952
1024
1024
1024
954
953
952
953
1024
952
```

Comment: water and air are not the extremes the sensor is probably designed for. How about if you try very moist soil and very dry soil?

Comment: @vicatcu I've updated the question with new info.